# Loop through all sub folder of and execute bat File?

Tags: loops, batch-file, call, directory

I am trying to have a bat file in a parent directory that loops through the sub folders and runs a bat file named `callshow.bat`.

Here is what I've got so far. I'm not very good at these so any help would be great!

```
for /r %%f in (*) do Call callshow.bat
```

Here is the folder Structure:

```
Example:
Parent:(Where new Bat file will be)
Sub Folder 1\folder1\callshow.bat
Sub Folder 2\folder2\callshow.bat
Sub Folder 3\folder3\callshow.bat
Sub Folder 4\folder4\callshow.bat
Sub Folder 5\folder5\callshow.bat
etc.......
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /r /d %%f in (*) do pushd "%%f" & Call "callshow.bat" & popd
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work for me, but thank for the help.

Comment: in "c:\bat files\callshow.bat" put @echo %cd% and then try it.  If there are no subdirectories then it will do nothing.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work either. I added the folder Structure, maybe that will help.

Comment: Now that you have clarified where callshow.bat is, I've removed the path to callshow.bat.

Comment: Both Work! Thanks guys, that's been driving me nuts all day!

Answer (score 3):

The folder structure made it much clearer, try this:

```
for /d /r %%i in (*) do if exist "%%i\callshow.bat" call "%%i\callshow.bat"
```

**EDIT:** This might work:

```
for /r %%f in (callshow.b?t) do call "%%f"
```

To get consistent results from `for /r` a wildcard needs to be used, hence `b?t`, even though it will match `callshow.bit` and `callshow.bbt` etc.

**EDIT 2:** This method (the one after EDIT:) can be used if `callshow.bat` does not refer to any files in the folder it is located in, or uses `%~dp0` to refer to them. Use this method especially if `callshow.bat` needs to use files located in the folder that the `call`ing batch file is located in. Otherwise, foxidrive's method can be used.

Comment: A problem with the methods you use is that the working directory is always the same - the folder you run the batch in, and not the folder where the callshow.bat resides.

Comment: @foxidrive It _does_ offer a simpler method, and might be an advantage depending on the code in `callshow.bat`..

Answer (score 2):

C:\test\batfiletorun.bat
C:\test\folder1\
C:\test\folder2\

To run batfiletorun.bat in folder1 and folder2:

From the command prompt:

for /r /d %f in (*) do pushd "%f" & Call C:\test\batfiletorun.bat & popd

Or, to run batfiletorun.bat using a .bat file would just have %% instead of % and look like the following with runbatfileinsubdirectories.bat consisting of the following line:

for /r /d %%f in (*) do pushd "%%f" & Call C:\test\batfiletorun.bat & popd

where now your inputs look like this:
C:\test\batfiletorun.bat
C:\test\runbatfileinsubdirectories.bat
C:\test\folder1\
C:\test\folder2\

Hope this simplifies things for someone out there. I used this to run a rename bat file in subdirectories.